# How to make call using Blackberry native sdk C/C++

Tags: blackberry-10

How to make call using Blackberry native sdk C/C++. I can't find library in documentation which can help to make in coming call.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [bb::system::phone::Phone](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__system__phone__phone.html) class to make a call. Your questions is not clear, do you want to make a call (outgoing) or accept a call (incoming).

Comment: Then initiateCellularCall or inititateCall in the Phone class should do what you need.